# Flutter Parsed Complex Json

Tags: json, flutter, parsing

I am having a problem on decoding the json from toMap(). I have no Issue on fromJson() function.
My main goal is to save it on shared preferences. all are working except for images i got null values

Here's my toMap() Method:
All Variables are working except for images;

```
        Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {

        var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        ImagesModel img = ImagesModel();
        Map<String, dynamic> imagesList = img.toMap();
        map["id"] = id;
        map["name"] = name;
        map["description"] = description;
        map["catalog_visibility"] = catalog_visibility;
        map["short_description"] = short_description;
        map["regular_price"] = regular_price;
        map["sale_price"] = sale_price;
        map["date_created"] = date_created;
        map['images'] = imagesList; --> I got null value on this images
        return map;
      }
```

Here's my Image Model

```
   class ImagesModel{
      final int id;
      final String src;
      final String name;

      ImagesModel({this.id, this.src, this.name});
      factory ImagesModel.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
        return ImagesModel(
          id: parsedJson['id'],
          src: parsedJson['src'],
          name: parsedJson['name']
        );
      }
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "src": src,
        "name" :name,
      };
    }
```

My Whole Products Model

```
      class ProductsModel {
      final int id;
      final String name;
      final String catalog_visibility;
      final String description;
      final String short_description;
      final String price;
      final String regular_price;
      final String sale_price;
      final String date_created;

      final List<CategoriesModel> categories;
      final List<ImagesModel> images;
      ProductsModel(
          {this.id,
          this.name,
          this.catalog_visibility,
          this.description,
          this.short_description,
          this.price,
          this.regular_price,
          this.sale_price,
          this.date_created,
          this.categories,
          this.images
          });

      factory ProductsModel.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
        var categoriesList = parsedJson['categories'] as List;
        var imagesList = parsedJson['images'] as List;
        List<ImagesModel> dataImages = imagesList.map((i) => ImagesModel.fromJSON(i)).toList();
        List<CategoriesModel> dataCategories =
        categoriesList.map((i) => CategoriesModel.fromJSON(i)).toList();
        return ProductsModel(
          id: parsedJson['id'],
          name: parsedJson['name'],
            catalog_visibility: parsedJson['catalog_visibility'],
            description: parsedJson['description'],
            short_description: parsedJson['short_description'],
            regular_price: parsedJson['regular_price'],
            sale_price: parsedJson['sale_price'],
            date_created: parsedJson['date_created'],
            categories: dataCategories,
          images: dataImages
        );

      }

      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {

        var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        ImagesModel img = ImagesModel();
        Map<String, dynamic> imagesList = img.toMap();
        map["id"] = id;
        map["name"] = name;
        map["description"] = description;
        map["catalog_visibility"] = catalog_visibility;
        map["short_description"] = short_description;
        map["regular_price"] = regular_price;
        map["sale_price"] = sale_price;
        map["date_created"] = date_created;
        map['images'] = imagesList;
        return map;
      }
    }
```

Comment: what does `print(imagesList)` show?

Comment: It shows  " images: {id: null, src: null, name: null} "

Comment: can you send JSON response?

Comment: so the problem is with saving data probably. you have one object inside the list but all values are null

Comment: @P4yam only images object is null and the remaining values on object(products) has a data

Comment: @Haryanvi the json data is too long to post it here.

Comment: Here's the complete decoded data from the shared preference

decode {id: 522, name: Enterprise, description: , catalog_visibility: visible, short_description: , regular_price: 60.00, sale_price: , date_created: 2020-06-02T09:29:43, images: {id: null, src: null, name: null}}

Comment: @aJaysanity so the problem is probably from just saving the image data, try to print the image when you are saving them and see if that is successful.

Comment: @aJaysanity put json inside you question. not in comment ( means edit you question)

Comment: @Haryanvi json response is too long I put it here on pastebin. I hope it will suffice https://pastebin.com/paZ1v6Hf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check **imagesList** null or not. Like

```
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {

        var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        ImagesModel img = ImagesModel();
        Map<String, dynamic> imagesList = img.toMap();
        map["id"] = id;
        map["name"] = name;
        map["description"] = description;
        map["catalog_visibility"] = catalog_visibility;
        map["short_description"] = short_description;
        map["regular_price"] = regular_price;
        map["sale_price"] = sale_price;
        map["date_created"] = date_created;

 
         if (this.images != null) {
        data['images'] = this.images.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
 
        return map;
      }
```

Comment: images: {id: null, src: null, name: null} here's the result on images. all products from id to data_created has a data

Comment: man, if you show complete Json. So its very easy to solve.

Comment: Ok Got IT, Do you want to save it all json to sharedPrefrence?

Comment: No. I just need what is on the productsmodel and image model.

Comment: please check. my ans

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217477/discussion-between-ajaysanity-and-haryanvi).

Answer (score 0):

The constuctor function has no parameters. Check this out.

```
ImagesModel img = ImagesModel(id:1,src:'value',name:'value');
```

.

```
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {

        var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        ImagesModel img = ImagesModel(id:1,src:'value',name:'value');
        Map<String, dynamic> imagesList = img.toMap();
        map["id"] = id;
        map["name"] = name;
        map["description"] = description;
        map["catalog_visibility"] = catalog_visibility;
        map["short_description"] = short_description;
        map["regular_price"] = regular_price;
        map["sale_price"] = sale_price;
        map["date_created"] = date_created;
        map['images'] = imagesList; --> I got null value on this images
        return map;
      }
```